# Azure AD App on Chrome Extension with chrome.identity?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, azure-authentication

I am using msal and aad in react environment to build a chrome extension. There was a problem sending the token from chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow . I can not figure out how to get the data of the user I entered. Next, I will present the main code

my manifest

```
{
  "name": "F Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "F extension help to find a job",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Lets start",   
    "default_popup": "index.html"  
  },
  "permissions": [ "storage","scripting", "identity"],
  "host_permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/re-Iogo-16.png",
    "32": "/images/re-Iogo-32.png",
    "48": "/images/re-Iogo-48.png",
    "128": "/images/re-Iogo-128.png"
    },
    "oauth2": {
      "client_id": "1f580835-************-8943****7ee",
      "scopes": ["openid", "email", "profile", "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation"],
      "redirect_uri": "chrome-extension://hneoplch****************mkod/index.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [ "*" ],
        "matches": [ "chrome-extension://**************ce***mkod/*" ]
      }
    ]
}
```

my authProvider

```
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from "./authConfig";

export const useSignIn = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      const tenant_id = "c7fa89c9-**************88b860"; // replace with your tenant ID
      const client_id = "1f580835-******************ac97ee"; // replace with your client ID
      const redirectUrl = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL(); // gets the redirect URL of the chrome extension
      //const redirectUrl = "chrome-extension://***************od/index.html";
      console.log(redirectUrl);
      const authUrl =
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" +
        tenant_id +
        "/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" +
        "response_type=token" +
        "&response_mode=fragment" +
        "&prompt=login" +
        "&client_id=" +
        client_id +
        "&redirect_uri=" +
        redirectUrl +
        "&scope=openid https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation profile";

      const responseWithToken = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
          {
            url: authUrl,
            interactive: true,
          },
          (redirectUrl) => {
            console.log("redirectUrl", redirectUrl);
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
              reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
              resolve(redirectUrl);
            }
          }
        );
      });

      // the access token needs to be extracted from the response.
      const token = responseWithToken.match(/(?<=access_token=).*(?=&token_type)/);
      chrome.storage.local.set({ azure_token: token }, function () {
        console.log("Value is set");
      });

      console.log("token", token);
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  return signIn;
};

export const useSignOut = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const signOut = () => {
    instance.logout();
  };
  return signOut;
};
```

after i take token i try to make fetch, but i met 401 error , component that i use to display some info

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import CalcSquareForm from "./components/CalcSquareForm";
import { InteractionType } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { useSignIn, useSignOut } from "./auth/authProvider";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const signIn = useSignIn();
  const signOut = useSignOut();

  function getUserData(accessToken) {
    return fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken[0]}`,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    const account = await signIn();
    console.log("account", account);
    getUserData(account);
    setUser(account);
  };

  const handleSignOut = () => {
    signOut();
    setUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {user ? (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome, {user[0]}!</p>
          <button onClick={handleSignOut}>Sign Out</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

I used `https://jwt.ms` as Redirect URI and enabled **Access Tokens** option in application like this:

[image]

When I ran below **authorization request** in browser by signing in with valid user account, I got consent screen like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<appID>
&response_type=token
&response_mode=fragment
&prompt=login
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=openid https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation profile
```

[image]

After accepting the above consent, I got **access token** successfully with **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims as below:

[image]

When I used this token to fetch signed-in user profile via Postman, I too got **401 error** like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you need to have either `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` or `https://graph.microsoft.com` as **audience** and `User.Read` in **scope** of access token.

To resolve the error, you need to add **User.Read** permission in scope by replacing https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation

I ran below **authorization request** in browser by modifying scope and got consent screen like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<appID>
&response_type=token
&response_mode=fragment
&prompt=login
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=openid User.Read profile
```

[image]

After accepting the above consent, I got **access token** with **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims as below:

[image]

When I used this token to fetch signed-in user profile via Postman, I got **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]